# Ideas for an overlay for really long webpages for mobile phones

Tags: iphone, mobile

I like reading faqs from GameFaqs.com and I'd like to read them on my iPhone. The problem is most game faqs are really, really long, which makes scrolling through them a big pain. Flicking through screen after screen of text takes a very long time.

I am not a web developer, but would there be a way to somehow create an overlay through which we can access a faq and that will give us commands like "search", "go to page", "next page" and "prev page"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unclear on what kind of solution you're looking for.  Presumably programming of some sort, since this is Stack Overflow. :-)

You could certainly write a native iPhone app that does this.  You could also write a proxy-type web service that does it.  Presumably those are obvious enough that they are not what you want.

You could do this with bookmarklets.  [These examples](http://www.lifeclever.com/17-powerful-bookmarklets-for-your-iphone/) include searching in the page already.

Comment: I was thinking it could be webpage that takes a URL and then reformats the URL's content in such a way you can skip to certain pages. The question is really vague, I know.

Answer (score 0):

There has actually already been something made that fixes this problem. It's called QuickScroll, and it's for jailbroken iPhones. Link here: http://moreinfo.thebigboss.org/moreinfo/quickscroll.php

Just search for "quickscroll" in Cydia. It's free, so go check it out!

Comment: Is there a solution available that doesn't require jailbreaking?

Comment: No. In order to modify Safari in a way such as this, it is necessary to have full access to the phone.

Comment: It wouldn't be difficult (just time consuming) to write an app-store compatible browser that has "jump to page" or some other type of scrolling functionality